# How to Sum the total of the duplicate row?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to sum up the total cost that which consultant is earning more by performing services, but since I need to get the cost from a service table and the amount of service performed from another table, the total Cost need to be combine two different column from two different table. However, it wont sum up the total cost that from duplicate rows.

There is two tables, Services_Performed and Service.

Service_Performed Table

```
Service_id|Temployee_id|ServicePerformed_Amount
----------|------------|-----------------------
         2|           1|                      2
----------|------------|-----------------------
         4|           1|                      1
----------|------------|-----------------------
         1|           3|                      3
----------|------------|-----------------------
         9|           3|                      5
----------|------------|-----------------------
         3|           5|                      5
----------|------------|-----------------------
        10|           5|                      4
----------|------------|-----------------------
         8|           5|                      1
```

Service Table

```
Service_id|Service_cost
----------|------------
         1|       18000 
----------|------------
         2|       20000
----------|------------
         3|       34000
----------|------------
         4|       16000
----------|------------
         5|       40588
----------|------------
         6|       20358
----------|------------
         7|       14852
```

And I used following query to get the total cost of the services based on how much they cost and how many is going to performed.

```
SELECT 
TECHNICAL.TEMPLOYEE_ID,CONSULTANT.EMP_NAME, 
SERVICES_PERFORMED.SP_AMOUNT * SERVICE.SER_COST AS TotalCost

FROM SERVICES_PERFORMED,TECHNICAL,CONSULTANT,SERVICE

WHERE TECHNICAL.TEMPLOYEE_ID = SERVICES_PERFORMED.TEMPLOYEE_ID AND
TECHNICAL.TEMPLOYEE_ID = CONSULTANT.EMPLOYEE_ID AND
SERVICES_PERFORMED.SERVICE_ID = SERVICE.SERVICE_ID

ORDER BY TotalCost DESC;
```

Here's the result:

```
    Temployee_id|Employee_name|TotalCost
    ------------|------------|----------
               3|         Kim|    179450
    ------------|------------|----------
               5|       David|    170000
    ------------|------------|----------
               5|       David|    143480
    ------------|------------|----------
               7|        Andy|    122148
    ------------|------------|----------
               9|       Oscar|    121764
    ------------|------------|----------
               3|         Kim|     54000
    ------------|------------|----------
               1|       Danny|     40000
```

But the main thing I want to do is SUM up the total cost and see who each the most from performing services.How can I sum up the amount for the same name.

Comment: use SUM() over(partition by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following

```
 SELECT 
 TECHNICAL.TEMPLOYEE_ID,CONSULTANT.EMP_NAME, 
 SUM(SERVICES_PERFORMED.SP_AMOUNT * SERVICE.SER_COST) AS TotalCost

 FROM SERVICES_PERFORMED,TECHNICAL,CONSULTANT,SERVICE

 WHERE TECHNICAL.TEMPLOYEE_ID = SERVICES_PERFORMED.TEMPLOYEE_ID AND
 TECHNICAL.TEMPLOYEE_ID = CONSULTANT.EMPLOYEE_ID AND
 SERVICES_PERFORMED.SERVICE_ID = SERVICE.SERVICE_ID

 GROUP BY TECHNICAL.TEMPLOYEE_ID,CONSULTANT.EMP_NAME
 ORDER BY TotalCost DESC;
```

Comment: It is working, but I tried use SUM before, it won't let me do that , just give me error.

Comment: U need GROUP BY to use aggregate function such as SUM, MAX.

Comment: Thank You So Much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.temployee_id,b.emp_name,Sum(c.service_cost) 
    FROM  service_performed a , consultatnt b,service c
     where a.temployee_id=b.temployee_id  AND  a.service_id=c.service_id
   GROUP BY  a.temployee_id,b.emp_name
```